# separate helper function to log in before every rspec request test is run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, specifications

I've been struggling with creating a login function that should be executed before any rspec test is run.

What I have right now is:

```
def login
  post "/session", { "session[username]" => "bjones" }
end
```

in my spec_helper.rb file

Then, I have the following in one of my spec.rb files in the requests directory.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Sessions" do
  describe "GET /dashboards" do

    login

    it "displays the dashboard" do
      get dashboard_path
      puts response.body
    end
  end
end
```

However, when I try running the test, I get:

```
undefined method `post' for #<Class:0x4f08828> (NoMethodError)
```

I'm pretty new to rails and completely new to testing and rspec so maybe there's something fundamental I'm missing here.  Basically, all I want to do is set that session variable so that when the test is run I will be logged in.  Perhaps a different approach would be better?  Or maybe I need to put that login function in a different place?

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738859/maintaining-session-with-capybara-and-rails-3?rq=1) answer which was sort of useful but it's not for rspec so I'm having trouble understanding where such a helper function would go.

Comment: Have you defined a login function in your sessions helper?

Comment: No, I was just assuming that I needed to include it in my spec_helper file.  Also my understanding was that only view and controller files have access to helper functions.

Comment: I assumed your app already had a login function and you were just trying to implement a separate one for testing. It's better to put helper methods like this for your tests in spec/support/utilities.rb (you have to create this file and directory), which will be automatically included. But I don't think that would solve the error you're getting. Is login defined inside of a module or class within 'spec_helper'?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
let(:login) {
  post "/session", { "username" => "bjones" }.to_json
}
```

This might have to be revised to use `.to_json` or not, depending on what content type the controller accepts.